# What's meaning of this exception?

Tags: android

I am showing image into listview from webservice suppose I am testing application 10 times
   then 6 time this exception comes please anyone help me.
                                                          I am calling web service using AsyncTask.

```
06-12 14:49:53.132: E/dalvikvm-heap(3071): Out of memory on a 1920016-byte allocation.
 06-12 14:49:53.160: E/AndroidRuntime(3071): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
 06-12 14:49:53.160: E/AndroidRuntime(3071): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error  occured while executing doInBackground()
  06-12 14:49:53.160: E/AndroidRuntime(3071):   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
 06-12 14:49:53.160: E/AndroidRuntime(3071):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
 06-12 14:49:53.160: E/AndroidRuntime(3071):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
 06-12 14:49:53.160: E/AndroidRuntime(3071):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
 06-12 14:49:53.160: E/AndroidRuntime(3071):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
 06-12 14:49:53.160: E/AndroidRuntime(3071):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
 06-12 14:49:53.160: E/AndroidRuntime(3071):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-12 14:49:53.160: E/AndroidRuntime(3071):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-12 14:49:53.160: E/AndroidRuntime(3071): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
 06-12 14:49:53.160: E/AndroidRuntime(3071):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
 06-12 14:49:53.160: E/AndroidRuntime(3071):    at an droid.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:493)
06-12 14:49:53.160: E/AndroidRuntime(3071):     at com.rentfaster.utilities.ImageLoader.decodeFile(ImageLoader.java:142)
06-12 14:49:53.160: E/AndroidRuntime(3071):     at com.rentfaster.utilities.ImageLoader.getBitmap(ImageLoader.java:78)
 06-12 14:49:53.160: E/AndroidRuntime(3071):    at com.rentfaster.handler.DetailPhotoHandler.imagefecher(DetailPhotoHandler.java:211)
  06-12 14:49:53.160: E/AndroidRuntime(3071):   at com.rentfaster.handler.DetailPhotoHandler.characters(DetailPhotoHandler.java:153)
 06-12 14:49:53.160: E/AndroidRuntime(3071):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.text(ExpatParser.java:163)
 06-12 14:49:53.160: E/AndroidRuntime(3071):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.appendBytes(Native Method)
 06-12 14:49:53.160: E/AndroidRuntime(3071):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseFragment(ExpatParser.java:513)
  06-12 14:49:53.160: E/AndroidRuntime(3071):   at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:474)
  06-12 14:49:53.160: E/AndroidRuntime(3071):   at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:321)
  06-12 14:49:53.160: E/AndroidRuntime(3071):   at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:279)
 06-12 14:49:53.160: E/AndroidRuntime(3071):    at com.rentfaster.home.PropertyDetail$Photostask.doInBackground(PropertyDetail.java:1174)
  06-12 14:49:53.160: E/AndroidRuntime(3071):   at com.rentfaster.home.PropertyDetail$Photostask.doInBackground(PropertyDetail.java:1)
06-12 14:49:53.160: E/AndroidRuntime(3071):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
06-12 14:49:53.160: E/AndroidRuntime(3071):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
06-12 14:49:53.160: E/AndroidRuntime(3071):     ... 4 more
06-12 14:50:02.882: E/parse exception0(3258):  dont know why
06-12 14:50:02.882: E/XML Error(3258): java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: &area=53.447557,-113.460058,53.447557,-113.460058&max=100
06-12 14:50:02.921: E/MapActivity(3258): Couldn't get connection factory client
```

I am still facing Out of memory problem ,I am using this code please help me

```
//decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private static Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
       try {
        //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inSampleSize = 2;
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
        }

        //decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        o2.inSampleSize=2;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, null);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Please post code so that we can analyze where exactly you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ran out of memory while Creating  bitmap coming from ,you need to reduce the size of bitmap using

```
 BitmapFactory.Options option = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    option.inSampleSize = 2;


Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(root.getPath() + "/" + imageName,
                            option);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Answer (score 0):

You ran out of memory while decoding bitmap coming from some stream (webservice?) 
Maybe you should deliver image  not as part of  message exchange ( where it will be 
base64 encoded and copied again and again polluting your precious heap )  but as separate request pulling binary stream from server?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a RuntimeException, which has been caused by an OutOfMemoryError. OutOfMemoryErrors usually happen when you try to load an image that is too large for the space allotted by Android to your application.

If you could post the following lines and some of the code above and below them, along with the calling method and explain what you're doing in your app, we can probably help you better:

```
ImageLoader.java:142
ImageLoader.java:78
DetailPhotoHandler.java:211
DetailPhotoHandler.java:153
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is `OutOfMemoryError`

These links should solve your issues,

[android how to handle out of memory exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544919/android-how-to-handle-out-of-memory-exception)
[How to handle out of memory error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035228/how-to-handle-out-of-memory-error)
[Android: out of memory exception in Gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238388/android-out-of-memory-exception-in-gallery)
[android - out of memory exception when creating bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697760/android-out-of-memory-exception-when-creating-bitmap)