# Bitmap out of memory exception

Tags: android

I use bitmaps in my application. After I use them I recycle them and set null. Eventhough I do that, at allocation tracker I can see that allocations for bitmaps aren't freed. It causes my application to crash...

Comment: please give me part sourse code when create and resycle Bitmap, and logs.

Comment: they are probably referenced somewhere

Comment: when will you get this memory memory error, at the time of resizing or convert into bitmap like that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle out of memory error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035228/how-to-handle-out-of-memory-error)

Answer (score 0):

This the part of code to over come memory issue, i used this code when i resize the bitmap,

```
public Bitmap custom_SizedImage(String intent_data2) {

        Options options = new Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(intent_data2, options);
        double sampleSize = 0;
        Boolean scaleByHeight = Math.abs(options.outHeight - targetHeight) >= Math
                .abs(options.outWidth - targetWidth);

        if (options.outHeight * options.outWidth * 2 >= 1638) {
            sampleSize = scaleByHeight ? options.outHeight / targetHeight
                    : options.outWidth / targetWidth;
            sampleSize = (int) Math.pow(2d,
                    Math.floor(Math.log(sampleSize) / Math.log(2d)));
        }
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inTempStorage = new byte[128];
        while (true) {
            try {
                options.inSampleSize = (int) sampleSize;
                           // here you can do you Decode process
                //mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(intent_data2, options);

                break;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                try {
                    sampleSize = sampleSize * 2;
                } catch (Exception ex1) {

                }
            }
        }
        return scaledBitmap;

    }
```